# Get all parent term taxonomy id and name of vocabulary

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary (*Vehicle*) which contains the following taxonomy terms.

- Maruti

  - Alto
  - Swift
  - Baleno
  - Barazza
- Hundai

  - I10
  - I20
  - Creta
- Tata

  - Nexon
  - Safari
  - Nano

I want to get only the parent taxonomy terms: *Maruti*, *Hundai*, and *Tata*.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't return the expected values.

```php
$parent = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadParents($termId);
```

Also the following code didn't work for me.

```php
$parents = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadAllParents('termid');
```

Comment: Are you aware that Drupal 8 reached end of life on November 2 2021? I have been asking this of people who are doing new work on Drupal 8 because there is nothing more important than upgrading to Drupal 9.

Comment: Yes i know D8 is reached end of life

Answer (score 2):

The methods you are mentioning accept as argument a term ID and return parents of this term.

You can use loadTree() providing the vocabulary name and for the second argument 0 to load the entire tree, but only for one level (third argument):

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('vehicle', 0, 1, TRUE);
```